# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\nu} \frac{e^{-\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} \, dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\nu} \frac{e^{-\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} \, dx$$

Is it possible to calculate this for $a>0$ and $\nu=0, 2$ ?

I think the result seems to include exponential integral function, but I failed to find the answer from the integration table.

I would be very grateful if you could share some of the good integration skills, ideas, or any advice.

Comment: I don't think it is in terms of exponential integrals.  At least [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+E%5E%28-Sqrt%5Bx%5E2%2B1%5D%29%2FSqrt%5Bx%5E2%2B1%5D+dx+from+0+to+Infinity) don't recognize this for $a=1,\nu=0$.

Comment: @user10354138 Yeah,, WA doesn't recognize it. The reason I wrote above like that was just intuition, actually, I had no reason. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x=a \sinh t$, then
$$I_1=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} dx= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-a \cosh t} dt=K_0(a),$$
where $K_{\nu}(x)$ is cylindrical modified Bessel function of order $\nu$.
Next, $$I_1=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 \frac{e^{-\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} dx=\frac{a^2}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} (\cosh 2t-1)~ e^{-a\cosh t} dt=\frac{a^2}{2} [K_2(a)-K_0(a)]$$
See for $K_{\nu}(z):$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function